# Finding minimum value in list of lists of lists of lists in python

Tags: python, list, min

I have this huge list of values that looks like this but is much larger:

CODE:

```
score= [
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0.14139999999999997]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0.19199999999999973]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0.1520999999999999]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0.13030000000000008], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0.06330000000000036], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0.0021999999999997577], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0.11419999999999986, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0.1459999999999999, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0.1772999999999998, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0.16239999999999988], [0, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0.1676000000000002], [0, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0.15149999999999997, 0], [0, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 0, 0.11219999999999963, 0], [0, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 0.023299999999999876, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 0.06959999999999988, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0]],
    [[0.010500000000000398, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0]],
    [[0.008799999999999919, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0]]
]

best_score = min(score, key=lambda row: row[-1])
print(best_score)
```

I need to get the row with smallest(non zero) value on each position, meaning something like this:
I tried to find it with min function, but that just gave me wierd results..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your desired result for this input? You wrote "something like this" but didn't write anything after it. Please provide a [mre] including what you've already tried. If you want more tips, check out [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps to get you started:

```
min_value = min([x for y in [num for sublist in score for num in sublist] for x in y if x != 0])
for row in score:
    if min_value in [num for sublist in row for num in sublist]:
        print(row)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0.0021999999999997577], [0]]
```

Comment: You can simplify that comp with a generator expression instead of a list and nested `for`s everywhere: `min_value = min(x for sublist in score for y in sublist for x in y if x != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `min()` function using a lambda key which sums the nested lists:

```py
best_score = min(score, key=lambda x: sum([sum(y) for y in x]))
print(best_score)
```

Output:

```py
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0.0021999999999997577], [0]]
```

The idea is that the key should be the sum of the row, and we do that by summing each nested list (`[sum(y) for y in x]`) and summing the results of that in the lambda expression.